# Retrieving properties from item in array by string in javascript

Tags: javascript

So I know I can retrieve properties from an object by string with bracket notation:

```js
const obj = {a:[
  {b: 'hi'},
]};

console.log(obj['a']); // Array [Object { b: "hi" }]
```

But if I try to access the item in the array with that notation, it doesn't allow it:

```js
console.log(obj['a[0].b']);  // undefined
console.log(obj['a[0]']);    // undefined
```

Is there a way to do this in javascript?

## Why am I doing this?

So my function is getting strings with array and object information like this:

- `"folder[2].people[1].name.firstName"`
- `"folder[2].people[1].name.lastName"`
- `"folder[2].name"`

and I need to get that information from the object itself. I'd prefer to not have to parse the string.

Comment: How are you constructing the string?

Comment: There is no `a[0]` as a property/key, that's why you get the error. Your object prop `a` is an array of objects.

Comment: What function is this that is returning these strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using... `eval()`? (more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval))

### WARNING: Never use eval()! (read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!))

```js
const obj = {
  a: [
    { b: 'hi' },
  ]
};
console.log(eval('obj.a[0].b'));
// prints "hi"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this: console.log(obj['a'][0].b);

```js
 const obj = {a:[
  {b: 'hi'},
]};
console.log(obj['a'][0].b);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're combining all your keys into a single string so it's looking for a key that matches that string.

Try

```
console.log(obj['a'][0])
console.log(obj['a'][0]['b'])
```

Answer (score 0):

if you run it on the browser console(F12)
it will be very clear

when you do `obj['a']` it already return the array `[{ b: 'hi' },]`
then you get b by `[{ b: 'hi' },][0].b`
so the correct way is `obj['a'][0].b`

`obj['a[0]']` means you trying to get

```
obj = { 
  'a[0]':??? // <= this
};
```

which doesn't exist

```js
const obj = {a:[
    {b: 'hi'},
  ]};
console.log("obj['a'] = ", obj['a']);
console.log("obj['a'][0] = ", obj['a'][0]);
console.log("obj['a'][0].b = ", obj['a'][0].b);
```

```js
obj = {'a[0]':"test"};
console.log(obj['a[0]']);
```